# AWS RedShift Copy SQL - how do I convert multiple values to NULL?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a RedShift COPY command which is executed as SQL:-

```
COPY some_schema.some_table FROM 's3://a-bucket/home/a_file.csv' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=SOMEKEY;aws_secret_access_key=SOMESECRETKEY' IGNOREHEADER 1 CSV DATEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' NULL 'NOT-CAPTURED'
```

The data I need to import has a date column with occasional occurrences of 'NOT-CAPTURED'. The addition of the NULL option allows these to be treated as null and prevents a load error. This apparently worked.

Can this statement be extended to treat multiple types of occurrence as null? I have 'N.A' in a date column in a similar file and would like to use a common statement?

I have tried obvious variations to provide more than one value to replace as null such as `NULL 'NOT-CAPTURED','N.A'` and couldn't find any documentation covering it.

Thanks!

Comment: A perfectly acceptable workaround that was suggested by a colleague was to use ```ACCEPTANYDATE``` in conjunction with a ```DATEFORMAT``` option since the issue was specific to a date column. However the correct syntax for multiple replacements would be an exact answer